# Any way to obtain the EC2 Identity Document private key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssl, certificate, pkcs#7

Is it possible to obtain the private key used to sign the EC2 Identity Document (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html) from within the instance, or in any other way? Assuming that one signs the Identity Document with this key I'm looking for, the OpenSSL command would be:

`openssl smime -sign -in document.txt -out document.p7 -outform pem -nodetach -inkey <private_key> -signer AWSpubkey`

Where `<private_key>` is the key I'm looking for.

I'm trying to determine if someone could potentially forge the PKCS7 signature in http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/pkcs7 by creating a `document.txt` and signing it with the private key.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As I mentioned in a comment below, my question is not really about Unix/Linux or security but about EC2 and if there is a way to obtain this private key. I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but the AWS forums are not very responsive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the point of Amazon doing this is that they don't publish the private key so there is no way for someone to forge the signature. Unless there are some breakthroughs in quantum computing soon, you should be confident that the signature hasn't been forged.

There's a [different Stack Exchange site](https://security.stackexchange.com/) where you are more likely to have your question answered by a cryptographic specialist.

Comment: Thanks for that. I know that EC2 generates a private key for every instance to create its identity document, and it'd be useless if that private key was somewhere in the instance or in the metadata because it'd mean that you could sign any identity document with that and still be valid against their public certificate. Just wanted to make sure there was no way of getting this private key. So it's more an EC2 question that a cryptography question. Thanks for the link to that Stack Exchange site anyway.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. I didn't realize there was a different private key for each EC2 instance, so I learned something today. As far as I know there is no way to get the private key though.

Comment: *"I know that EC2 generates a private key for every instance to create its identity document..."* @nanodgb I'm skeptical of this claim.  A single public key can't have infinite matching private keys, yet that seems to be what you are suggesting is the case.  What's your source for this?

Comment: I guess I must have gotten confused with their identity metadata endpoints being `/document`, `/signature`, `/pkcs7` and `/rsa2048`... It gave the impression there was private key generated at launch. But you'r right, you can't have multiple private keys for one public key, and it wouldn't make sense to sign the identity document with a generated private key if it is to be verified against a common public key... So, I guess I can be sure that AWS won't share their private key :)